# Acceleration, velocity and positions of an automobile in the three dimensions

Tags: kalman-filter

I am a student who is researching on the application of Kalman Filter in automobiles.
To find the predicted state matrix of the new position and the velocity of an automobile in the three dimensions, i need the following data:
1) velocity in all three directions
2) acceleration of the automobile in the three dimensions. All in a unit time given that the car starts its motion from origin. 
I need at least 6 seperate sets of measurements of the above variable so i can calculate a state matrix of a kalman filter. Hence, i am also in need of 6  sets of values which contain the velocity and distance of the car after the same fixed intervals in which i have a the velocity , acceleration and the error in these measurements.
These two sets of data will enable me to produce a good estimate for 6 different positions and velocities.
Hence allowing me to show the potential of Kalman Filer in satellites.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what is the question

Comment: need 6 different sets of data about a car for my kalman filter:
Each data set will contain:
1) Velocity for the car in the three dimensions
2) Position of the car in the three dimensions

I am assuming that these different sets of data were calculated by a GPS of a car after fixed interval of time.
These six data will be compared my Kalman filter and i will produce six new estimates.

So sir my question is:
1) Where can i get these authentic real life six sets of data so my estimates are relatable and have more credibility?

Regards

Comment: I would first probably generate the data using a script to test my Kalman filter (not actually use real data). If you are looking for real data - one way is to use your android in your car to record GPS coordinates(position) and acceleration (not sure how to get velocity without just integrating acceleration).

Comment: Thank you. was a great help